# Is there a workaround for rowcount in pyodbc?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I know that in a select statement with SQL Server pydobc many times will return -1 for performance or because the results haven't loaded. I do understand this is expected behavior. what I'm wondering is if there is a way around this. currently I'm working with a conditional while loop to make calls to an API that includes the query results:

```
stmt_list = """
SELECT TOP 5
some_columns
,some_other_columns
FROM somedb
ORDER BY some_columns DESC; """
try:
    runloop = True
    while runloop:
        cur.execute(stmt_list)
        if cur != None and cur.rowcount > 0:
            #Set up some objects and make calls to an API
        else:
            runloop = False
            break
```

when I run the above code, the loop never iterates because the rowcount comes back as -1.

Comment: I've actually found a workaround for this on my own, its a little sloppy but it works for now. I used a for loop to iterate through the results

Comment: You could `SELECT COUNT( enter stuff here )` before your query.

Comment: I assume you're just trying to make sure the query returns values right?